# keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: publicKey's is not X.509, but X509 in OpenJDK 1.8.162

Tags: java, x509, keytool, public-key

I am trying to generate a key using the command

```
keytool -genkey -dname CN=<>, OU=AB, O=AB, L=AB, ST=AB, C=US -alias myalias -keypass pwd -keystore C:/tmp_1.54/serverKeystore -storepass pwd -storetype PKCS12 -providername JsafeJCE -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 360
```

But I am getting the below error while running the keytool. I am using OpenJDK 1.8.162.

```
Error : keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: publicKey's is not X.
509, but X509
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: publicKey's is not X.509, but X509
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen.generate(CertAndKeyGen.java:
162)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doGenKeyPair(Main.java:1739)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1007)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)
```

Need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please check this bug [JDK-8054019 : Keytool Error publicKey's is not X.509, but X509](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8054019). Is JsafeJCE a restriction to you? Have you tried with other providers?

Comment: I checked that link but it did not help. We are using JsafeJCE provider only. Did not try with other providers. Is there anything which you suggest to use.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. I was trying to first enable FIPS (using RSA Bsafe) in OpenJDK 1.8 and then was trying to enable SSL in the product which was throwing this error. Later on I changed the order doing first SSL and then enable FIPS which worked seamlessly.  Here the issue what I found was OpenJDK 1.8 does not support RSA Bsafe libraries before SSL is enabled.